# Ocaml summing up values in an integer list

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm facing a syntax error in the code below:

```
let sum list =
let current_sum = List.hd list in
for i = 1 to List.length list - 1 do
let counter = List.nth list i
    current_sum = current_sum + counter 
done;;
```

The error that I'm facing is here

```
done;
^^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

The code is supposed  to sum up the current values of the list at each iteration, for example

```
sum [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 6; 10]
```

So I think I'm going about this in the right direction, what I don't understand is why this error keeps popping up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword `in` is missing in the `let counter` statement.

Another error that will pop after : `current_sum` is immutable. You will have to change this.

Another way to achieve your sum : use List.fold function.

Putting in shape the comments below :

```
let sum_l l = 
   let (r,_) = List.fold_left 
      (fun (a_l, a_i) x -> ((a_i + x) :: a_l , a_i+x))
      ([],0) l in
   List.rev r;;
```

Comment: I'll fiddle around with the fold function for a bit, but the more I play around with Ocaml the more I realize for loops aren't that handy, thanks again mate, I'll probably need more help if that's OK

Comment: yep... loop is a structure very common in imperative programming style. In ocaml, you will use function & recursion. You will change the way you see programs ;).  Some useful links : https://github.com/rizo/awesome-ocaml and https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html. May be you know them already.

Comment: Yeah i know of them :D, can i use List.fold so that i create a function that sums up the integers at each iteration and stores them in a list like this :

Comment: [1;2;3;4] -> [1;3;6;10] ?

Comment: yes, you can. Starting point (I let you fix the code & finalize) : List.fold (fun (acc_l,acc) x -> ( (acc+x) :: acc_l,acc+x) ) ([], 0) l;;

Comment: I didn't completely understand fold which is why I have been avoiding using it, if I understood correctly acc refers to accumulator, but why do we have 2 here? For both lists? And for the second variable the ([], 0) the variables are an empty list and a zero?

Comment: fold allow to iterate a function on an accumulator. List.fold_left f a [b1; ...; bn] is f (... (f (f a b1) b2) ...) bn (from ocaml site). here, a (the accumulator) is a tuple made of the list you want to get, and the second  element is the cumulative sum... the starting point of the accumulator is hence ([],0). The result will be the reverse expected list. Up to you to reverse it again.

Comment: The reversing would have to be after the function executes right? But if that's the case where would i do that? Since it would return the result directly?

Comment: it is a matter of computational complexity. adding an element at the beginning of a list costs nothing ; adding an element at the end of a list (what you could do to get the result in one shot) has a linear cost - and it will result to time computation being squared to the size of list. whereas getting first the reverse result, and reverse it again will be a linear time complexity.

Comment: Ok so i tried to reverse the product list but i think the way i'm going about this is wrong have a look please     `let counter = [] in List.fold_left (fun (acc_l,acc) x -> ( (acc+x) :: acc_l,acc+x) ) (List.rev counter, 0) l;;`

Comment: My idea was to replace the list with a variable so that i would be able to apply the list functions to them, but i couldn't get it to work :/, and adding an element to the end of the list can be done with the append function right? And time complexity in this case isn't an issue

Comment: I let you find yourself by experimenting in utop ;) . Regarding append : this is what cost a linear time ; but, you can use it in a first place if computational time is not an issue.

Comment: try first with smaller example : how to compute the sum of a list using List.fold_left for instance.

Comment: If i were to use append would it be like this?    `List.fold_left (fun (acc_l,acc) x -> ( List.rev_append [acc+x] acc_l,acc+x) ) ([], 0) l;;`

Comment: Never mind i figured it out, but how can i make it only return the list, i can't specify return values in Ocaml can i ? The code is  ` List.fold_left (fun (acc_l,acc) x -> ( List.append acc_l [acc+x],acc+x) ) ([], 0) l;; `

Comment: by using pattern matching : let (result,_) = List.fold..... ;; or using fst function which takes the first element out of a tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, if we ever meet somehow i'm buying you a beer :)

Answer (score 4):

You have simply forgotten the `in` keywork in your line 4.

However, OCaml is a [functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), and you're trying to use an imperative method here.

Even though it will work when you solve your syntax error, it is not the way you would do this in OCaml. For example, a function summing up the elements of a integer list can be done with the following:

```
let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0;;
```

or even

```
let sum = List.reduce ~f:(+);;
```

if you're using the [Core](https://github.com/janestreet/core) library.

**EDIT**

After reading the comments under another answer, I've understood what you're *really* trying to do:

```
# sum [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 6; 10]
```

And here is a way to do so, using OCaml's functional features:

```
let sum l =
  let sums =
    List.fold_left (fun l x -> match l with
      | [] -> [x]
      | h::t -> (x+h)::l) [] l
  in List.rev sums;;
```

The code is more complicated than just computing the sum itself, but it does the trick.